# Python list sum all occurrences preserving order

Tags: python-3.x, list

Given a tabular data structure, which I have called `pop(0)` on, but will show header for clarity. Basically its an `id` in string format and two value entries in float format.

```
#header
['id','value1','value2']

data=
['1001',25,10],
['1001',25,0],
['1002',100,0],
['1002',100,0],
['1002',100,0],
['1003',150,10]...
```

And given a vector containing only the unique `ids`:

```
ids = ['1001','1002','1003']
```

I aim to create another vector that stores the sum of all `value1` (can ignore `value2` for now) while preserving the order in `ids`. Desired output:

```
print(ids, sum_result)
1001 50
1002 300
1003 150
```

I had made some headway with a dict approach, but I later painfully realized that the order was not preserved.

### Question

How might we iterate over each unique element in `ids` and sum all occurrences of that id in `data`? In my actual data, there are also some "Nones" and "NaN"s for `value1s` if that helps narrow the solution set for anyone.

**Note:** Would prefer native python

Comment: are other libraries possible? With pandas.groupby it would be quite easy, or itertools.groupby.

Comment: @Rabinzel I'd prefer native python but will note pandas approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` requires that the input be sorted by the key first. A more generic and readable approach would be to iterate through the list of records and build a dict by aggregating the values of the same keys. Use a `collections.defaultdict` to initialize new keys easily:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    ['1001', 25, 10],
    ['1001', 25, 0],
    ['1002', 100, 0],
    ['1002', 100, 0],
    ['1002', 100, 0],
    ['1003', 150, 10]
]

output = defaultdict(int)
for id, *values in data:
    output[id] += values[0] if values else 0

for id, sum_result in output.items():
    print(id, sum_result)
```

This outputs:

```
1001 50
1002 300
1003 150
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use pandas module (https://pandas.pydata.org/)
First you load your data into DataFrame, then you use list to filter and groupby. Order is preserved.

```
import pandas as pd
data=[
    ['1001',25,10],
    ['1001',25,0],
    ['1002',100,0],
    ['1002',100,0],
    ['1002',100,0],
    ['1003',150,10]
  ]
ids = ['1001','1002']

#load list into dataframe; there are many ways to create dataframe;
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
#lets add column names
df_data.columns=['id','value1','value2']

#filter using isin and group by first column (0), use sum
result = df_data[df_data['id'].isin(ids)].groupby(by=['id']).agg(sum)
```

Output: #result.head()

```
        value1  value2
id
1001    50      10
1002    300     0
```

to access result by index and column name

```
print(result.loc['1001']['value1'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> Make an iterator that returns **consecutive** keys and groups from the iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each element. [...] That behavior differs from SQL’s GROUP BY which aggregates common elements regardless of their input order.

This is very convenient in your case because `itertools.groupby()` groups consecutive elements with the same key. This example should make everything clearer:

```
>>> print([list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAA')]) 
[
    ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
    ['B', 'B', 'B'], 
    ['C', 'C'], 
    ['D'], 
    ['A', 'A']
]
```

---

To answer your question:

```
from itertools import groupby

data=[
    ['1001',25,10],
    ['1001',25,0],
    ['1002',100,0],
    ['1002',100,0],
    ['1002',100,0],
    ['1003',150,10]
]

DEFAULT_VALUE_WHEN_NONE = 0

result = [(key, sum(map(lambda x: DEFAULT_VALUE_WHEN_NONE if x[1] is None or math.isnan(x[1]) else x[1], group))) 
          for key, group in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0])]
    
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('1001', 50), ('1002', 300), ('1003', 150)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it yourself using a nested for loop:

```
data = [
    ['1001', 25, 10],
    ['1001', 25, 0],
    ['1002', 100, 0],
    ['1002', 100, 0],
    ['1002', 100, 0],
    ['1003', 150, 10]
]

ids = ['1003','1001', '1003']

result = [[id, 0] for id in ids]

for row in data:
    for idx in range(len(result)):
        if row[0] == result[idx][0]:
            result[idx][1] += row[1]

print(result)
```

Note that using pandas for such purpose is much slower.